# Laravel: define the route if it is same as public folder subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel

I have `admin` subfolder in the `public` folder, but I want to define the specific response on `mywebsite.loc/admin`. Currently, if to input `mywebsite.loc/admin`, it will be next response:

[image]

However I has the routes definition for `admin`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/', [
        'as' => 'AdminTop',
        'uses' => //Admin\AdminController@renderTopPage'
        function(){ 
            dd('ok');
        }
    ]);       
});
```

How I can make it work?

Comment: This kind of reveals a bigger problem with your setup in that people can browse through your files under public. I think you need to block that

Comment: @apokryfos, but how?

Comment: you probably have an `Indexes` option in either your htaccess or apache configuration which should be either removed or made into `-Indexes`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create any folder in public and you want to use this folder as a route then you need to add your index.php which is useful for understanding this folder as a root.

For example, you create one folder in public/admin now you copy your public/index.php file into your admin folder and change two line in this index.php file

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

**TO**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

**And**

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

**TO**

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
```

I think it helps in your requirements.

> Sorry for my bad english

Comment: if it's work for you than accept my answer it's help other one

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have a default .htaccess with the correct rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Which means if not directory (!-d) and not file (!-f), route to index.php (else hit the file/directory)

try removing the line that ends with `!-d`, but i suggest you make a change to your directory name, as it will be a problem at some point for you.